# AssetImage Image Not showing

Tags: flutter-assetimage

Somehow I cannot load an image into my app. Can you please help? Added the directory into pubspec.yaml

```
Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.8,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                      left: 16.0,
                      top: 16.0,
                      bottom: 16.0,
                      right: 16.0,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage("assets/pictures/NYC_01/NYC_01_01.webp"),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover
                          )
                        )
                      ),
                    ),
```